# Populating listbox in WPF from a database

Tags: c#, sql, database, wpf

I want to populate a listbox from a database and then display it on a wpf window. I then want to be able to select an item from the listbox and display corresponding information from the database, from the same table that populated the listbox.

These are the tables that I have:

```
CREATE TABLE LoginTable(
UserID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
email varchar(255) NOT NULL,
password varchar(255) NOT NULL
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE UserInfo(
UserID INT,
modName varchar(255),
modCode varchar(8),
credits INT,
ClassPW INT,
CONSTRAINT FK_UserInfo FOREIGN KEY (UserID) REFERENCES LoginTable
);
```

I want to populate the listbox with modCode.

This is what I managed to do:

```
string com = "Select modCode from UserInfo where UserID ='" + CommonClass.userID + "'";
SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(com, con);
DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
adpt.Fill(myDataSet, "UserInfo");
DataTable myDataTable = myDataSet.Tables[0];
DataRow tempRow = null;
foreach (DataRow tempRow_Variable in myDataTable.Rows)
{
    tempRow = tempRow_Variable;
    listbox.Items.Add((tempRow["ModCode"]));
}
```

It displays the modCode, but I don't know how to then use it to get further information from the table in the datbase.

Comment: You can add an `OnChange` event to the list box, and then query the new data based on the value that has changed. Then display the queries data in another control.

Answer (score 0):

This task is much easier if you break it down into distinct steps.

1 - Create model classes for each database table.

e.g.

```
public class UserInfo
{
    public int UserId {get;set;}
    public string ModName {get; set;}
    public string ModCode {get;set;}
    public int Credits {get;set;}
    public int ClassPW {get;set;}   
}
```

2 - Create a data access module that returns a collection of each model class as required. You might want use an ORM library such as EntityFramework, Dapper or OrmLite to help with this.

3 - In your UI, set the ItemsSource of your ComboBox to the UserInfo collection and set the DisplayMemberPath to ModCode. Then in the OnChanged event of your ComboBox, the SelectedItem will be a UserInfo instance that you can then access for the other properties as required.